# Beginner. plotting in python unable to recognize anything following the exponent

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot

I am trying to plot x^8 - 1 but python is only plotting the x^8.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DNwJy.jpg)

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question please don't put code as an image.  We cannot see it and have to flick back to the question.  It is a pain

Comment: The `-1` is insignificant in your scale `1e8`.